# Example of using ADO.NET with Oracle in WCF

Tags: wcf, ado.net

Without any Linq or Entity Framework, I would like to see an example of using ADO.NET with Oracle in WCF.  I have seen the ABC's and the different contracts, but with say consuming a Restful WCF service sending in 1 to several parameters I would like to see an example of using this type of code:

```
            connection = new OracleConnection(EnvironmentSettings.connectionString);
            connection.Open();

            command = new OracleCommand("H16.WEB_FACILITY.get_facility_info", connection);
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            // Input Parameters
            command.Parameters.Add("pfcode", OracleDbType.Varchar2, facilityCode, ParameterDirection.Input);
            // Output Parameters
            command.Parameters.Add("pfacility", OracleDbType.RefCursor).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(command);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(ds);
```

So that I can do CRUD operations will a WCF good practice design.   Fault Contracts / Data Contracts  etc...   I see many examples, but not specific to something that seems so simple.  I guess that it why so many people are still doing asmx ... I'm wanting to convert a project I am on and I see tons of asmx web services everywhere and wish for an expert or someone who has done this to point my in the right direction or even better show me how to write that ADO code into WCF ...  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slightly confusted as to exactly what you mean, but Linq and EntityFramework have nothing to do with WCF, and the paradigm doesn't change one bit in using them. You could do something as simple as:

```
[ServiceContract]
public class MyService
{

    [OperationContract]
    public DataSet LoadData(string facilityCode)
    {
        command = new OracleCommand("H16.WEB_FACILITY.get_facility_info", connection);
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        // Input Parameters
        command.Parameters.Add("pfcode", OracleDbType.Varchar2, facilityCode, ParameterDirection.Input);
        // Output Parameters
        command.Parameters.Add("pfacility", OracleDbType.RefCursor).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

        adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(command);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(ds);

        return ds;
    }

}
```

---

In practice you would probably want to use a `[DataContract]` class, and return that instead of a `DataSet`, but the only real change would be reading your results into a real class instead of a DataSet, something like:

```
[DataContract]
public class MyData
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Facility { get; set; }
}
```

Then your service method returns that instead of DataSet:

```
[OperationContract]
public MyData LoadData(string facilityCode)
{
    MyData data;
    // read from Oracle into data object...
    return data;
}
```

---

You can also look at [WCF Transaction Flow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733116.aspx) to control your database transaction scope. It is a nice way to have every WCF service operation be trapped in its own transaction scope, or even control the transaction from the WCF client if needed.

---

`[FaultContract]`s are a subject on their own, but you can find some good examples if you google for it. Basically you would set up your own exception type, and then add that to the service like:

```
[ServiceContract]
[FaultContract(typeof(MyException))]
public class MyService
```

and that tells WCF to add the serialization info for MyException to the WSDL, so then your operations can `throw new MyException();` and that will serialize back to the clients, so they will get your exception.

Comment: Yes, I prefer to avoid using a DataSet.  In the OperationContract would it be best to place try /catch blocks there?  If there is an error how does the FaultContract get called, from the Catch?  Ideally I will be consuming this with MVC 3 application thus when the mvc application is consuming the service it would be ideal to make the call and get back the data OR get back an error.   Thanks in advance for any additional help/explanations on it.  This is very helpful.

Comment: @Tom Stickel - You can actually centralize your error handling by adding a ServiceBehavior that implements `IErrorHandler`. There is a pretty good example of that here: http://weblogs.asp.net/pglavich/archive/2008/10/16/wcf-ierrorhandler-and-propagating-faults.aspx  If you do not do that, then by default, WCF will catch any unhandled exceptions, and wrap them in a `FaultException<>`. If your FaultContract is `[FaultContract(typeofMyException)]` then client side, you would: `try { wcfService.Load(); } catch (FaultException<MyException> ex) { MyException myEx = ex.Detail; }`